# ES6 import syntax in Node.js app with Babel and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, babeljs

index.ts:

```
import express from "express"
const app = express()
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!!"))
```

.babelrc:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript", "@babel/preset-env"],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

The command `npx babel-node src/index.ts` gives an error:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import express from "express"
                                                                     ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

However, if I rename `index.ts` to `index.js` and run command `npx babel-node src/index.js` then it works fine.

Alternatively, if I change the first line of index.ts to `const express = require("express")` then the command (for `index.ts`) also works fine.

So it looks like I can either use ES6 import syntax or use Typescript, but not both.

How to fix this, if possible?

The following modules are installed:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/node": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.3.3",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.5.5",
"tslint": "^5.18.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.3"
"@types/express": "^4.17.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Webpack-Generator](https://createapp.dev) babel and Typescript combination. It gives all require setting for ES6 and TypeScript config.